# Bootstrap Header Text Ellipssing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am looking to ellipse one of the header Text components when the viewport size is small to prevent the header from wrapping and becoming two lines.

Details here : https://jsfiddle.net/3L8ch5bo/7/ As you change the width of the viewport - you will see that the header goes into two lines.

I would like it to the ellipse in this way : https://jsfiddle.net/vsj896as/1/

The problem with ellipsing shown above is that it forces the header to be a fixed length. Is there a way to have it ellipsed based on size of the viewport (using max-width: calc(..) for example).

Please note that the "Left Text" on the header is non-standard bootstrap header component and is causing the complexity. It is needed and cannot be shortened and should be displayed in full.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Here is the html code :

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="pull-left headComp">Left Text</div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-items-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand ellipsed">How to Ellipse This Very Very Long Header Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-items-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url1">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url2">Getting Started</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url3">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url4">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Jumbo Message</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to complete what you want. The code attached and in the provided jsfiddle checks the viewport size on document.ready. If the size is less than 768px the text within the .navbar-brand will shorten.

The .resize event triggers the responsive part. If viewport is greater than 768px then the original text will show else if the viewport is less than the shortened text will show.

Hope that helps or at least points you in the right direction.

view jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/1zs700od/1/)

```js
$(function(){

var $startingView = $(window).width();
var $startingBrand = $('.navbar-brand');

if($startingView < 768) {
 $startingBrand.text("How To...")
}
 
 $(window).resize(function(){
 
 var $viewportWidth = $(window).width();
 var $brand = $(".navbar-brand");
 var originalTitle = "How to Ellipse This Very Very Long Header Text";
 var shortTitle = "How To...";
 
  if($viewportWidth < 768) {
   $brand.text(shortTitle);
  }else{
   $brand.text(originalTitle);
  }
 
 });
});
```

```css
.headComp {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 16px;
  width: 95px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="pull-left headComp">Left Text</div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-items-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">How to Ellipse This Very Very Long Header Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-items-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url1">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url2">Getting Started</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url3">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a target="_blank" href="url4">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Jumbo Message</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time and sorry I was not clear. I am looking for the header-text to be displayed as much as possible (not just How To...). So based on viewport size of the device (not just for less than 768). I was also looking for css only solution if possible. But if this must be done using js, then so be it..